# reset all tabs when logged out iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on a project in which I authenticate the user using login. When I logout, the user come back to the login page.The problem I have is when the user logs out and log's in again the user is shown in the same tab from which he logged out and the data is still stored.

I build a tabbar application and in the 1st tab i present the login using modular view and in each tab when I call logout present the login using modular view. So its just a tabbar applicaiton in which login is presented modularly.

Can any one please tell me how to fix this or do I have any structural flaw? I really appreciate your time for looking int this.

Thanks

Comment: No, unless you provide some code.

Comment: I added more information. Please let me know if you need code.

Comment: Can you tell me which part of the code do you need?

Comment: I think maybe you need to structure it so that your modal view controller is the tabbed application interface and when you log out it gets dismissed and the user is returned to the root view controller (login screen), not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The act of presenting a modal view will never clear out the underlying views data after being presented (that would be entirely bizarre).

So you have to manually clean up your views on logout - either by implementing a reset method on the view controllers that erases the information displayed in the views and that you call during your logout processing (i.e. clears text fields, lists etc.), or by (on logout as well) releasing the individual view controllers or the whole tab view controller and recreating it again on login.

Comment: I actually wanted to implement login in a viewcontroller and then load a tabbar controller. I did not know how to proceed with that So I started this way. My project is in infant stage. Can you please give me some suggestion on how to proceed or what changes will help to implement in the right way.

Comment: Both approaches get used - I prefer the approach of not using a modal view controller but making presentation of login a function of application state. You can change root view controllers by removing the view controllers view from the main application window and adding another view to the application window (you could do this in your application delegate).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about how your views are structured, I would suggest that you need to pop and release the view controller containing the info when the user selects to log out.

I would think that there is a call that creates the view after the initial login? Releasing it would flush the captured data in the view, and a new view would be created by the existing code.

If that answer isn't any help to you, please edit your question and add details on how your view structure looks.

Comment: Can you tell me which part of the code do you need. I mean app delegate or each view controller or anything else.I build a tabbar application and in the 1st tab i present the login using modular view and in each tab when I call logout present the login using modular view. So its just a tabbar applicaiton in which login is presented modularly.

Comment: Since you present the login view as a modal view from the view containing the data, my suggested solution won't work. You need to add a call to refresh the data in the visible view at login time.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your tabBarController selectedIndex property just before you present your login view modally.

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0]; // first tab is 0
```

To clear the data, simply do it when the user logs out.